Is there a way to access inherited xml:space from a given element?
Considering some XML like so -
<root>
   <foo>
       <bar xml:space="preserve">
         <baz>
           TEXT
         </baz>
       </bar>
   </foo>
</root>

My application needs to observe xml:space="preserve" for the text inside the baz element, in order to avoid trimming its content down to "TEXT" (which is the default behaviour of my application). But in my example this attribute is defined on an ancestor. (It could be any ancestor, at any depth)
I believe this whitespace handling should be inherited from bar > baz, but I don't want to walk up the tree for every text node I extract (or make additional xpath queries). My application doesn't encounter every node along root > foo > bar > baz, but the underlying libxml parser must have done!
I know I can iterate on parentNode up to the root, but I want to access the space handling behaviour of the DOMElement or DOMText directly if at all possible. Is there some property or method that I'm missing?

Does this answer your question? How to select xml elements by an attribute name containing a colon in PHP (domx)?

You can also check out this comment in the manual on how it's done using SimpleXML

Thanks, but I know how to use xpath and query the tree. My question was whether the inherited value is exposed to PHP via the final element it affects. If the answer is "no", then "no" is fine.
